"Failed to initialize account" when running Counter Example Solana Program
I'm new to Solana and I tried running the Counter example Solana program. When I go to the counter page and press create, I get the error Failed To Initialize Account.
The error message for this says WalletSignTransactionError: User rejected the request. even though I pressed confirm.
I also have 2 SOL in my wallet, which is connected to the same network as the one that the program is running on (dev network).
Link to Repo: https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/tree/main/basics/counter
Any help would be awesome, thanks.





Which counter example. can you post a link to the repository please?

@JonasH. https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/tree/main/basics/counter This one, thank you!

@JonasH. I noticed it might be because it says Transaction Reverted During Simulation on Phantom. How would I fix this?

@123, please tell me about your frontend code base and also which counter are used?
maybe anchor in this url?
https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/tree/main/basics/counter

I followed this tutorial https://solana.com/developers/guides/dapps/journal#setting-up-the-project
So basically I followed these steps:
Enter project name: my-journal-dapp
Select a preset: Next.js
Select a UI library: Tailwind
Select an Anchor template: counter program
And so I'm guessing that I did use anchor in that URL? Thanks

Can you share your code?
and what is that url?
https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/tree/main/basics/counter
You mean you use this smart contract for your project?

Ok, i put it on github. Thanks https://github.com/matthew-lim-matthew-lim/blockchain-journal. Thanks again for helping me

I've checked your code base.
It is working well in my side.
Please check your contract is deployed successfully.
And check console log if you fetch error again.
https://ibb.co/Pt1KSK1
please check image.
I think the main reason is that contract is not deployed.

Thanks, thats good to hear. I deployed the rust contract, and then I changed myjournaldapp.json to have address set to the Program Id from deploying the rust contract. Then, I ran npm run dev, which resulted in the same error that I had before.
If its okay, do you mind going through the steps that you took from cloning the repo to getting it working?
Thanks again

At, first, Please check your transaction in on-chain if it is success or not.
You don't have to change program id in myjournaldapp.json because it will be automatically changed.
Just deploy and run. that's it.

Hey, thanks for your help. I'm not sure what happened, but I just deleted my repository and then remade it and it works now. I think it is tied to this thread that the dev responded to. I don't really understand what they are talking about here, but it seems like exactly the issue I had.
https://github.com/solana-developers/create-solana-dapp/issues/94
Also, do you mind explaining the process?
So clearly to deploy the app I need to build and then deploy eg with
npm run anchor build
npm run anchor deploy
Am I missing anything?

I think what happened was that before the dev fixed the bug, the address in myjournaldapp.json was different from the one in lib.rs.

Yeah you are right, but at first, you missed something,
You have to run command anchor keys sync in anchor project directory.
This command will sync your program id.

Yeah thats exactly right, thank you @pizzza1bit. Can I ask how you learnt Solana? What resources did you use?

https://solana.com/developers/courses
